# Find rows that contain a specific number

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to return results from a SELECT *WHERE* clause that finds matches for exact numbers - by this, if taking 9 as an example I mean the number 9 and not 29 which includes the number 9.

Imagine the following text values in a table with a varchar column...

- a sample 12th
- 9th sample
- 999
- some text 9
- 9a

To clarify, the number may be at the very start of the string or it may not, in either case the query should find it.

It's important that the query can work if other characters such as letters as well as symbols are next to the required number.    Using 9 as an example, looking at the 5 lines in the list above this would mean that list items 2, 4 and 5 are valid.

Sample 3 is not valid - if I were to use a *LIKE* clause sample 3 would naturally be returned which I don't want.

I thought that LOCATE(9,COLUMN_NAME) may work but it has the same issue as a LIKE clause.

If it's only going to be a regular expression to fix this can someone suggest what it would be ?    I have the PHP equivalent:

```
/\d+/
```

... but not sure how to rewrite it for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regexp such as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'a sample 12th' AS col UNION ALL
    SELECT '9th' UNION ALL
    SELECT '999' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'some text 9' UNION ALL
    SELECT '9a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'foo9bar' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'foo99bar' 
) AS t
WHERE col REGEXP '([[:<:]]|[^[:digit:]])9([^[:digit:]]|[[:>:]])'
```

The regexp means 9 is surrounded by non digits or a word boundary so for example it will match `foo9bar` but not `foo99bar`.

Comment: The first one seems to work, thanks very much!  Out of interest, what versions of MySQL use the 2nd library?  Is this platform dependant or version, do you know ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201782/discussion-between-adamjones-and-salman-a).

Answer (score 0):

a very simple using 2 conditions

```
select * from label where v like '%9%'and v not regexp '9[0-9]*9' ;
```

other example  : in case you are looking for 9 at every position not followed or preceded  by  9

```
select * from label where v regexp '^\(.*[^9]\)?9\([^9].*\)?$' ;
```

other example : you are looking for 9 at the first position

```
select * from label where v regexp '^9\([^9].*\)?$' ;
```

a sqlfiddle inspired by questions and comments

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da68d6/1

link to the documentation 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: this is almost perfect but it does still pick up wrong numbers.   Change your schema to add a record with 939.  The two sql queries (the 1st is preferable) will will still pick that up.

Comment: Just to say, would love to see a traditional regex version of this solution,.. if you know how to modify @EchoMike444 please share if you have a second ;)

Comment: please update your question and tell us if 939 is valid  .

Comment: and what is valid for foo9bar and foo99bar ?

Comment: These examples don't work for me @EchoMike444, they return records when the number contains 9 within a different number (ie 29) which isn't what I want.    They also don't seem to work if the number is at the very start of the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201783/discussion-between-adamjones-and-echomike444).